# How to remove focus on input in angular?

Tags: angular

Is there any method or any way to remove focus on input field in Angular?

I could not able to focus out using clearfocus() method.I have tried like this.

```
@ViewChild("textbox1") el: ElementRef;
this.el.nativeElement.clearFocus();
```

Comment: try `this.el.nativeElement.blur()`

Comment: Although @TimMartens is right, you should not do that, since you don't want to handle the DOM yourself and using `nativeElement` is bad practice. Could you tell us what you want to do ?

Comment: Why's that in this particular instance, @trichetriche?

Comment: It's not, i didn't say `you must not`, I said `you should not`.

Comment: I keep hearing that this is "bad practice" as well. But I have not seen an alternative for things such as setting and clearing focus. Maybe with the updated compiler in v7 we'll have another option? Until then, "bad practice" or not ... I use it often. I just put `if (this.el.nativeElement)` around it just in case.

Comment: @TimMartens i heard that it is the bad practise but i have not found any solution. Thank yo for suggestion. It`s working fine.

Comment: according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12463) this will not be implemented for now in the native API

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to address this while avoiding putting representation logic into your component code.

My solution involves a custom directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
    selector: "[blurOn]"
})
export class BlurOnDirective implements OnDestroy {

    private _attachedEvent: EventEmitter<void> | null = null;
    private _eventSubscription: Subscription | null = null;

    public constructor(private readonly _element: ElementRef) {
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this._eventSubscription)
            this._eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    @Input("blurOn")
    public set attachedEvent(value: EventEmitter<void> | null) {
        if (this._attachedEvent === value) 
            return;

        if (this._eventSubscription)
            this._eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
        this._attachedEvent = value;
        if (value)
            this._eventSubscription = value.subscribe(() => this.onEvent());
    }

    private onEvent(): void {
        const nativeElement: any = this._element.nativeElement;
        if (typeof(nativeElement.blur) === "function")
            nativeElement.blur();
    }

}
```

Add an event to your component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    ...
})
export class YourComponent {

    public readonly submittedValue: EventEmitter<void>;

    public submitValue(): void {
        this.submittedValue.emit();
    }

}
```

Loosely couple View with ViewModel logic:

```
<input [blurOn]="submittedValue"></input>
```

Comment: Normally at least one button on the form.. just set focus to that.. document.getById('my-button').focus();